# PostgreSQL extract hour and group by with 0 sum values doesn't show results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL request in Postgres

```
SELECT CAST(extract(hour from
                    CAST("public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."datecreation" AS timestamp)) AS integer) AS "datecreation",
       "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."refspecialty"                                              AS "refspecialty",
       "Refspecialty"."label"                                                                  AS "label",
       COALESCE(count(distinct "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."iddialogue"), 0)                   AS "count",
       COALESCE(sum("public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."timespent"), 0)                               AS "heures"
FROM "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"
         LEFT JOIN "public"."v_mdiddoctors" "Refuser" ON "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."refuser" = "Refuser"."iduser"
         LEFT JOIN "public"."v_mdparamspecialties" "Refspecialty"
                   ON "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."refspecialty" = "Refspecialty"."idspecialty"
WHERE (date_trunc('month', CAST("public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."datecreation" AS timestamp)) BETWEEN date_trunc('month',
                                                                                                             CAST(
                                                                                                                     (CAST(now() AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '-3 month')) AS timestamp)) AND date_trunc('month', CAST(now() AS timestamp)) AND
       "Refspecialty"."label" = 'Dermatologie' AND
       "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."codedialogueaction" in ('RESPONSE', 'TRANSFER'))
  AND extract('dow' FROM "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."datecreation") IN (0, 6)
GROUP BY CAST(extract(hour from CAST("public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."datecreation" AS timestamp)) AS integer),
         "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."refspecialty", "Refspecialty"."label"
ORDER BY CAST(extract(hour from CAST("public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."datecreation" AS timestamp)) AS integer) ASC,
         "public"."v_mdmeddialogues"."refspecialty" ASC, "Refspecialty"."label" ASC;
```

The problem is that there's no value that "happened" between 4 and 5 am and therefore the results show :
[image]

My tables are :

```
    create table mdmeddialogues
(
    iddialogue         varchar(255),
    codedialoguetype   varchar(255),
    refdialogueroot    bigint,
    codedialogueaction varchar(255),
    refuser            varchar(255),
    refspecialty       varchar(255),
    datecreation       timestamp,
    refoperator        varchar(255),
    source             varchar(255),
    timespent          bigint,
    datelastupdate     timestamp
);

create table mdparamspecialties
(
    idspecialty    varchar(255),
    code           varchar(255),
    label          varchar(255),
    active         bit,
    exclusive      bit,
    valid          bit,
    datelastupdate timestamp
);
```

As you can see the result skips the value 4 in `datecreation`. How can I show this row with empty values (0) in `count` and `heures` ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Yes, it was pointed out by @Hambone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is separate from your question, but adding an alias to `v_mdmeddialogues` and doing a little bit of formatting can really help a lot in terms of the readability of your query.  Also, you have a lot of unnecessary casting, casting timestamps as timestamps, for example.  I am assuming `datecreation` is a text field, in which case I left the cast in place, but if that's a date/time, then that cast is also unnecessary and even a little misleading.  Finally the excess quotes, in my opinion, are a distraction.  The only time you NEED quotes is when quotes are in the DDL of the table, which I strongly discourage in just about every instance.

Anyway, a quick refactoring of your original query with the above observations might look like this (to keep it simple I aliased public.v_mdmeddialogues as "md"):

```
SELECT
   extract (hour from md.datecreation) AS datecreation,
   md.refspecialty AS refspecialty,
   Refspecialty.label AS label,
   COALESCE(count(distinct md.iddialogue), 0) AS count,
   COALESCE(sum(md.timespent), 0)  AS heures
FROM
   mdmeddialogues md
   LEFT JOIN mdiddoctors Refuser ON 
     md.refuser = Refuser.iduser
   LEFT JOIN mdparamspecialties Refspecialty
     ON md.refspecialty = Refspecialty.idspecialty
WHERE
  date_trunc('month', md.datecreation) BETWEEN
    date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '3 month' AND 
    date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) AND
  Refspecialty.label = 'Dermatologie' AND
  md.codedialogueaction in ('RESPONSE', 'TRANSFER') and
  extract('dow' FROM md.datecreation) IN (0, 6)
GROUP BY
  datecreation, md.refspecialty, Refspecialty.label
ORDER BY
  datecreation ASC, md.refspecialty ASC, Refspecialty.label ASC;
```

Disclaimer: It's possible I messed one or two things up, but hopefully you can see this is more readable and easier to understand.

Now on to your problem.  If you have a known dataset as the output, you can generate that dataset and then left outer join our query.  In this case, it looks like you want a guaranteed 0-23.  For this, you can use a `generate_series (0, 23)` to create those and then left join off of that:

```
SELECT
   gs.datecreation,
   md.refspecialty AS refspecialty,
   Refspecialty.label AS label,
   COALESCE(count(distinct md.iddialogue), 0) AS count,
   COALESCE(sum(md.timespent), 0)  AS heures
FROM
   generate_series (0, 23) gs (datecreation)
   left join mdmeddialogues md on
     gs.datecreation = extract (hour from md.datecreation) and 
     date_trunc('month', md.datecreation) BETWEEN
        date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '3 month' AND 
        date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) AND
     md.codedialogueaction in ('RESPONSE', 'TRANSFER') and
     extract('dow' FROM md.datecreation) IN (0, 6)
   LEFT JOIN mdiddoctors Refuser ON 
     md.refuser = Refuser.iduser
   LEFT JOIN mdparamspecialties Refspecialty on
     md.refspecialty = Refspecialty.idspecialty and
     Refspecialty.label = 'Dermatologie'
GROUP BY
  gs.datecreation, md.refspecialty, Refspecialty.label
ORDER BY
  gs.datecreation ASC, md.refspecialty ASC, Refspecialty.label ASC;
```

If you are wanting the `refspecialty` and `label` values to also show up, that's another matter.  Since one of those two values is hardcoded in the where clause, you could just add that to the coalesce.

Comment: Hello @Hambone I did as you said by cleaning the request and adding the "generate series" but the result is still the same as before. I think that the LEFT JOIN is the problem because this line 
LEFT JOIN public.v_mdmeddialogues as md on extract(hour from md.datecreation :: timestamp) = gs
Has 0 results

Comment: Can you post the DDL for your tables?

Comment: I posted them on my first question

Comment: Yeah, indeed... That's what happens when I don't test stuff before answering. So, based on the DDL, I removed a couple of additional unnecessary casts (timestamp to timestamp), and I fixed some syntax errors where I failed to apply the alias consistently. On the second SQL statement, I made the classic mistake of putting the where conditions in the where clause, thereby making the left joins equivalent to inner joins. Try the above and see if it helps. Without data, it's impossible to tell for sure, but I think it's directionally very close to what you want.

Comment: this is the result : https://share.getcloudapp.com/ApurKnPr
It's not perfect but good enough. Thank you very much